# c FIle I/O write function has another bytes?

Tags: c, posix

When i made Student information file in C some problem occurs.

One Student information is made char[20],float,int,int (32bytes)
and I have 1000 Student informations.

if use fwrite (FILE* fp) output file is 32,000 bytes correctly but
using write(int fd) output file is 32,021 bytes. what is the 21 bytes??(I'm using Visual Studio 2017)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

typedef struct{
    unsigned int ID;
    char name[20];
    float score;
    int age;
} Student;

Student student;

int main(int args,char* argv[]){
 FILE* smp;
 fp = fopen("Sample.txt","r")    // sample.txt is consist of number of information, name,ID,score,age line by line

 int fd = open("out_student.dat",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT);
 //FILE *fp = open("out_student.dat","wb");
 int count = 0;
 fscanf(smp,"%d",&count);
 fseek(smp,2,SEEK_CUR);
 for(int i = 0;i<count;i++)
   {
     memset(student.name, 0, 20);
      for (index = 0; index<128; index++)
      {
        char temp;
        fread(&temp, 1, 1, smp);
        if (temp == ',')
            break;
      }
      fseek(smp, -index - 1, SEEK_CUR);
      fread(&student.name, 1, index, smp);
      fseek(smp, 1, SEEK_CUR);
      fscanf(smp, "%d", &student.ID);
      fseek(smp, 1, SEEK_CUR);
      fscanf(smp, "%f", &student.score);
      fseek(smp, 1, SEEK_CUR);
      fscanf(smp, "%d", &student.age);
      fseek(smp, 2, SEEK_CUR);
      write(fd,&student,sizeof(Student));
      //fwrite(&student,sizeof(Student),1,fp)  this output file is 32,000 bytes
  }    // output file is 32,021!! what is the 21 bytes?

fclose(smp);
close(fd);  //fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) show the code 2) look in the file 3) try to reproduce it with 1 or 0 records instead of 1000

Comment: Provide some [MCVE]. Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). [Use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program. Notice that `write` is not standard C, but POSIX (so you need some other tag)

Comment: What’s `fd`? Where’s the last closing brace? Please show the real code, and the version with `fwrite`.

Comment: Well, what happens if you fc the two different output files?

Comment: what's mean fc??

Comment: fc is a file comparison utility on Windows, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fc. Martin was asking what the difference in content between the files was that accounted for their difference in size.